# What is a good document size for a Flash presentation on a widescreen TV?

Tags: flash, user-interface

I am creating a presentation in Flash, which will be displayed on a 42" or a 50" TV at a booth at a trade show, fed by a laptop.  What are the best document dimensions to work with? Thanks.

Comment: This question *is* programming related; cloudhead is designing an app and needs some advice on selecting screen resolution issues.  This is something I've deal with in the past with programming.

Comment: I wouldnt exactly class flash presentations and television size's as a programming question...

Comment: I suppose it isn't directly, but it is relevant to programming.  Probably a better initial place for this would have been superuser.

Comment: So you would put this in the same class as this question?

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1088049/where-can-i-find-a-good-book-holder-for-decent-sized-programming-books-closed

A flash movie is a chunk of executable code (a SWF file) that is compiled based on a set of instructions in an FLA file.  That sounds like programming to me.  Whether the program is stored in a text file or whether it's a bunch of symbols and instructions entered in a different fashion (via the Flash timeline interface) it's still a program, in that it instructs the computer what to do.

Comment: I disagree, he's designing a presentation, I doubt a question about the size of a MS PowerPoint presentation would stay open. If it was a question about ActionScript then fair enough... but page dimensions?

Comment: I thought it was relevant enough. The dimensions affect performance. Flash straddles programming and design, but I didn't think it would cause a debate. A Flash developer covers a wide range of tasks, and since I saw a "Flash" tag, I asked a question related to Flash. It's difficult to force a Flash developer to spread his/her questions across multiple sites. However, if only ActionScript questions should be asked, perhaps the Flash tag should be omitted altogether.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you don't know ahead of time what model of TV you'll connect to, the best advice is to use the standard 720p resolution of 1280x720 or 1080i resolution of 1920x1080.

Comment: Assuming this is an HD display.

Comment: The title says widescreen, and the question says 42" or 50" display. I think HD is a reasonable assumption.

Comment: It may not be; widescreen 40"+ 16x9 SD (640x480) displays exist, I own one in fact. Some larger corporate video monitors in the 40-50 range do SD-only. Your'e probably right though.

Answer (score 3):

The best you can do is to find the native resolution of the TV (I'm hoping it is some kind of LCD screen) and take that as a resolution. That way you have the least problems with resizing turning out ugly. This is of course also hoping the laptop is able to connect to the screen at that resolution, but usually that isn't a big problem.

Hope this helps!

Comment: The TV manual should have either the native resolution, or the maximum resolution through the DVI input.

Answer (score 2):

Common resolutions for those displays are any of your standard widescreen resolutions from 1366 x 768 to 1920 x 1080, or in some cases 1920 x 1200. I'm willing to bet that if your display is a consumer product it's native resolution will be pretty close to 1366 x 768.

Comment: 1366×768 is probably the best resolution, because if it's connected with a VGA cable, that will (probably) be the resolution that the TV will claim to support.

Answer (score 2):

**Use vector graphics**; Flash supports that.  A vector-based presentation will resize natively and auto-scale to the TV/display's native resolution without any issues.

It's a really good practice to make stuff for trade shows using vector graphics anyways:

- They look very beautiful when you let the hardware deal with the graphics.
- They will look good on *any* display, not just the one for the show.  This is useful for marketing, as they can then use this presentation at other times: demoing for customers at meetings, showing stuff on their laptop, using the presentation on a projector, etc.
- Your'e not locked into a specific monitor / screen resolution for your app.  At the last minute, a large hippopotamus may rampage into the trade show hall and decide that your 42" TV is a whoopie cushion.  Or, less likely, someone accidentally spills their coffee into the DVI port an hour before the show starts.  With a vector graphics presentation, this is easily resolved.

These issues came back to bite our team in prepping our system for use at a tradeshow.  Marketing will love you, and ultimately sell more units, if you use vector graphics.

Comment: This is true, but one issue to watch out for is that using exclusively vector graphics would preclude using any photographic images.  Converting a photograph to vector graphics usually turns it into something pretty unpleasant looking.  So, for example, all that nice stock photography of people in business suits using laptops is right out :).  There is still a way to get around this using fluid layout but it requires a lot of extra work that Flash isn't going to do for you.

Answer (score 1):

As others have said, your first step is to find out the different possible resolutions on the laptop video card/TV.  These will determine the dimensions of your Flash movie.  However a more important consideration is -- will people be able to see/read the information you are displaying on the screen?

One way to do this before you actually get access to the screen is to find out the actual size (in inches, not pixels) of the display.  Then print out mockups of your visuals (especially ones with small text) in that exact size and tape it to the wall and look at it.  Is it too big?  Too small?  You may have to change the design.

Before the actual trade show you would really be advised to actually get your hands on the display hardware itself and test out the Flash.  This is especially advisable if it's an interactive (touchscreen) piece, for example.  Your best bet is to test on the target platform.